# Generating button clicked event on Jquery Dialog on ENTER Press?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i have below function in my jsp which create and opens the dialog. There is textbox in this dalog. What i want is when i enter on this dialogue
CreateCustomer button should be licked

```
function createCustomerDialog(){
    $("#createCustomerDialog").dialog( {
        title :  ""Create Customer,
           buttons : {
          'CreateCustomer' : function() {

         },
          'Cancel': function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
      });
      $("#createCustomerDialog").dialog("open");

}
```

i tried this  but dnot working

```
 $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane > button:last').focus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On dialog input's onKeyPress event check for a keycode == 13 (ENTER key), when this code is reached just click your button.

```
$("#yourInputId").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        $("#yourButtonId").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use .click() method instead .focus() in this code:

```
 $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane > button:last').focus();
```

And I think you should try button:first selector, because CreateCustomer button will first.

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            alert('Delete all items clicked');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            alert('Cancel clicked');
                }
            }
        });
```

And in browser console try this:

```
$('.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first').click();
```